# SWIFT: url encoding not working as per expectation

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, encoding

I have a URL like this:-

```
XXX/XXX/Detail?Type=9&query=L&TFH
```

As you can see I have a parameter valued `L&TFH` 
So when I tried to use

```
let urlStr = path.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)
```

it doesn't encode "&" and if I tried to encode specifically "&" in UTF-8 encoding, URL changes like

```
XXX/XXX/Detail?Type=9%26query=L%26TFH
```

which is also not a correct URL.

I don't want to encode every parameter individually as it multiple APIs has same requirements.

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: `addingPercentEncoding` cannot recognize whether y`&` belongs to a parameter value or separates parameters.  Take a look at `NSURLCompoments` which allows you the creation of valid urls very easily.

Comment: query params should be percent encoded before forming url with them, either via `URLQueryItem` and `URLCompoments`, or applying percentencoding manually.